# Why the datanode status reflected unknown when trying to join cluster after removing?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After I used the "remove-datanode [DataNodeID]" script to remove a datanode in Apache IoTDB, IoTDB prompted successfully removed. I deleted all the contents in the datanode directory, and then started it to join the cluster. After joining, the status always shows unknown, but this node can be connected through cli tool, and the latest data can also be found. I don't know why the status has always been unknown. What might be going on? I now use IoTDB version 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is data in your datanode, you can clear all the content in the data directory and try agin; if there are only empty datanodes, you can try to restart all confignodes of Apache IoTDB to see if this error still occurs.